# export and import of 3D arrays

Tags: list-manipulation, export, import

I have a very large (up to 1 Mio elements) 3D array

```
A = {{{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8}},{{9,10,11,12},{13,14,15,16}}, ......, {{....},{....},{....}}}
```

which I want to Export in one notebook and then Import it again in another notebook. *Necessary is that the array structure is preserved during this Export/Import operation.*
When I do

```
Export["Data.dat",A,"Table"]
```

followed - in the other notebook - by

```
B = Import["Data.dat","Table"]
```

I get a list with double commas in the innermost list:

```
B = {{{1,,2,,3,,4},{5,,6,,7,,8}},{{9,,10,,11,,12},{13,,14,,15,,16}},....{{....},{....},{....}}}
```

How can I get rid of these double commas in the innermost list?

Comment: It seems to coerce it to a list of strings, same if you use "List" instead of "Table" too. I get around it by using `Compress` on the 3d data first and exporting it to a text file, then `Uncompress` after importing it back in.

Comment: Since you are importing and exporting from the same computer, presumably, you could look into `DumpSave`. Beware that the produced files may not be cross-platform compatible.

Answer (score 2):

Table format (.dat) stores a *two-dimensional* array or a Grid to a Table file. Generalized, multi-dimensional data arrays cannot be stored using Table format.

Instead, use Wolfram Exchange Format ([WXF](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/WXF.html)) or Wolfram Data Exchange ([WDX](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/WDX.html)) format. WXF and WDX formats store arbitrary Wolfram Language expressions in a serialized, platform-independent form. Use `Export["data.wxf",expr]` or `Export["data.wdx",expr]` to export, and `Import["data.wxf"]` or `Import["data.wdx"]` to import.

Comment: many thanks for all your solutions. In the meantime I had experimented and simply by trial and error I discovered that simply doing ```Ev >> ordered-events.dat``` for the output and then ```Ev = << ordered-events.dat``` does everything correctly. 
What is the drawback to this simple method? Why is that not even mentioned in 
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InputAndOutputInNotebooks.html

Comment: [Put](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Put.html) (>>) writes expressions to a file in [InputForm](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm.html), or optionally, [OutputForm](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OutputForm.html). `Export`/`Import` converts expressions to and from a file format that corresponds to the file extension you choose. `Put` is simpler in that it can't convert to a specific format. `Export` and `Import` provide more options. The tutorial isn't about writing and reading files. It explains how to enter and display expressions with Mathematica.

Comment: ... You're welcome. The [Files, Streams, and External Operations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FilesStreamsAndExternalOperations.html) tutorial has information about storing data into files.

Comment: I had the same problem with .dat, and  .wxf worked.